# How do I change image every 2 second using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, so basically i'm trying to create my own portfolio website, and i want these image "text" to be changed every 2 second...

How can i do that using my following code?

Jquery

```
        $("document").ready(function(){
            $("a").on("mouseover", function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

                var selection =$(this).html();
                var imgfolder ="images/";
                var new_image;

                switch(selection){
                    case "C#" :
                        new_image = image + "C#-Programmer.png";
                        break;
                    case "Java" :
                        new_image = image + "JAVA-Programmer.png";
                        break;
                    case "HTML" :
                        new_image = image + "HTML-Programmer.png";
                        break;
                    case "DMD" :
                        new_image = image + "Digital-Media-Designer.png";
                        break;
                    case "network" :
                        new_image = image + "Network-Engineer.png";
                        break;
                    default:
                        new_image =  + "UX-Designer.png";
                        break;
                }
                $("img").attr("src", new_image);
            });
            $("#hide").on("click",function(){
                $("img").fadeOut(1000,function(){
                    alert("fadeout completed")
                });
            });
            $("#show").on("click",function(){
                $("img").fadeIn(1000);
            });


        });
```

This is my html code

```
<img src="image/UX-Designer.png" alt="c#"/>
```

Comment: Take a look about setInterval() Method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @smdsgn said, use `setInterval` to create a timer based event. I would also recommend using an array of image locations and iterating through them that way. This doesn't seem the like the best use for a switch statement.

```js
var images = [
 "images/img1.jpg",
  "iamges/img2.jpg",
  "images/img3.jpg"
]
var current = 0;
setInterval(function(){
   
  $('#flip').attr('src', images[current]);
  current = (current < images.length - 1)? current + 1: 0;

},1000); /*1000 = 1 sec*/
```

```css
#flip{
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="flip" src="">
```

Comment: Sorry, but what does this code means? 


{ current = (current < images.length - 1)? current + 1: 0; } ?

Comment: @Vexasoe It's called a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It is a quick way to write an if / else statement. Take a look at that link.

Comment: instead of messing the code with ternary & complex logic. Use ```images[current%number_of_images]```. And simply do ```current++```